# How to show Save As Dialog on ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm newbie on asp.net, i am developing Online Report Generator, i want to let the client to choose where he/she want to put his/her files so this is my code but didn't seems to work, it returning to my ajax error statement my ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExtractFolder"] is equal to "c:\temp\": just want to ask what's wrong with the code?

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";            
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+filename);
context.Response.WriteFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExtractFolder"]+filename);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting

Comment: Are you calling this code via AJAX? That could be your problem. Hazarding a guess this code was designed for a full page postback, not an AJAX request.

Comment: @JonP yes sir i am calling it via AJAX , before this code i am creating an excel after creating i save it to temp then the code above

Comment: @Balaji my error says unexpected token P..

Comment: Your problem is not in the code. `unexpected token` is a javascript error. Reading together with `ajax` you mentioned, I think you are actually trying to download the file via ajax request. That is not possible. Just set `window.location.href="your_url"` instead of sending ajax request to `your_url` and it will work I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String FileName = "FileName.txt";
String FilePath = "C:/...."; //Replace this
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

For more content types check our http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type#List_of_common_media_types

Answer (score 0):

First, check that your source file you want to send to the user is in c:\temp\ and that you have set *filename* to the name of the file you are sending.  Next you will want to make sure that your .net process has permission to c:\temp on your server.  It probably doesn't.

Also, make sure you understand that *response.writefile* actually reads a file from the server and writes it out to the browser.  You can't specify where the user saves the file to locally, this is handled by the browser not by your code.

Using Coders sample code make sure you change the following (see my comments)

```
String FileName = "FileName.xlsx";   //MAKE SURE THIS IS YOUR EXCEL FILENAME ON YOUR SERVER
String FilePath = "C:/...."; //SET THIS TO THE FOLDER THE FILE IS IN (put your file in your root folder of your website for now, you can move it later once you get the download code working)
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; //MAKE SURE YOU HAVE CHANGED THIS TOO
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

I also suggest trying the above in a standalone page first then incorporate it into your AJAX page once you know its working.

Comment: Actually the lines `context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";            
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+filename);` are signalling to the browser that a file is being supplied to download and it should open the save file dialogue. Yoou are correct that you can't controll where teh user saves the file.

Comment: Thank you for answering sir, i am sure that i have the file on temp, but i am not sure about the permission, if possible sir can you provide me a code for creating an excel file to the client side? ive been searching for two days can't find one...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't do what you want to do the way you are trying to do it.

The ASP.net code that you have is dependant on being part of a full http Request/Response cycle. The part where it is setting headers is where it telling the browser to download stuff.

An AJAX request is looking for a specific return with its request, generally javascript passable data. You are not returning this but rather the contents of a file.

Here's an [article](http://encosia.com/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/) the explains the concepts and problems a little more. It also provides you an alternate solution. Basically the solution revolves around using an iFrame to handle the file download request.